# Angularjs initialize multiple controllers at startup?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

i have a normal navbar with a menuController, this is the parent.

then i have two other controllers a DashBoardController this is loaded on startup and a LoadDataController this is called if i click a Link in my navbar.

it do the routing with the routeprovider like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html', controller: 'DashBoardController'})
$routeProvider.when('/loadData', {templateUrl: 'partials/loadData.html', controller: 'LoadDataController'})
```

in my LoadDataController i have a function for example doSomething();.. and if i click on a link in my navbar it routes me to the loadData site.. there it should call the doSomething() function. i want not use ng-init i want do this with an broadcast event! The problem is now, if i click on the Link in my navbar, it delegates me to the loadData.html site and sends a broadcast event, but at this moment the $on method in my LoadDataController is not initialized so the method is never called. How can i solve this problem ? is it possible that i can initialize my DashBoard an LoadDataController on startup?so that both controllers the DashBoard and my LoadDataController are initialized if i enter my index site?

**EDIT:**
@Dayan no i want not call a special function every time at initialization!  my menucontroller is initalized at startup and is the parent controller. below this controller are two other controllers my DashBoard and my LoadDataController. In my Navbar i have different links that should call different functions in my LoadDataController. The problem is now, that the broadcast event did not reach the LoadDataController because at this moment the $on method is not initialized.. for example.. i have in my navbar a link that calls a function in my navbarcontroller like this:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('callFunctionInLoadDataControllerEvent', null);
$location.path('/loadData');
```

and in my LoadDataController i have the $on method that shoud call a special function like this:

```
$scope.$on('callFunctionInLoadDataControllerEvent', function(scope, data) {

$scope.specialFunction();

}
```

the problem is now, i send my broadcast and at this time the LoadDataCOntroller is not initialized(and so the $on mehtod is also not initialized, the event never reaches my controller), the initizations starts first, if i change the path with $location.path('/loadData');

Comment: if you want to execute the function every time your controller is instantiated just executed at the beginning of the controller. if thats not your intention please, provide more details because am a little confused on under what conditions are you calling doSomething()

Comment: If you don't mind using another useful angular module try https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router, it has multi views/abstract view/ nested views that you can use to create partials with the specific controller you want.

Comment: I have edited my first post, hope its clearer what i mean.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this? I am coming across a similar issue.